# Using R package data in function without loading it

Tags: r

Does anyone know of a way (creative hack or otherwise) that data from an R package can be utilized inside a function without actually loading it to the environment?

As a simple example:

```
 plot.sepals <- function() {
     data(iris);
     plot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data=iris);
 }
```

You'll notice when you run the example that the `iris` dataset gets loaded. This is precisely what I wish to avoid. I'd like to use the data but not have it loaded to an environment.

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me? You mean that you want the data to be used in your function execution but immediatly after you want it to be unloaded from the environment?

Comment: well, if you want not to download the entire object into memory you can consider 'ff' or 'ffbase' packages. In fact, you will place only the pointer into memory but the physical data are placed on your drives.

Comment: Not load what? the data or the package?

Comment: You mean like this? `plot.sepals <- function() {
    plot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data=datasets::iris)
}` This way it is not loaded in the environment, but you'll access it directly from the package namespace (at least I think that it works that way).

Comment: Thank you, user. This is exactly what I was looking for. Not sure why I didn't try this before.

Comment: Good question (+1) and I think you could perhaps explain the meaning of "not load it" a little bit more for other readers. My interpretation (if I look at the answer) is: `iris` shall not be loaded into the global environment of R (what `dat(iris)` does) but used directly in your function. So if you want to improve your question for other readers with similar problems an edit would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm still not allowed to comment yet, but I think that @user3293236 answered your question as I understand it.

You mean like this?

```
plot.sepals <- function() { 
               plot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data=datasets::iris) }
```

Comment: Perfect! I wanted to use the diamonds data set w/o loading ggplot. Thanks!